# Using Directive in Angular2

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

[enter link description here](https://www.braceyourself.io/ng2-prism/)

I am trying to use Prism in my angular2 project. It has been said to do the following:

```
import {Codeblock} from 'ng2-prism/codeblock';
import {Ruby} from 'ng2-prism/languages';
```

and then

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  // ...
  directives: [Codeblock, Ruby]
})
```

But I am not able to do the third step. 
`directives: [Codeblock, Ruby]` throws an error always.

Comment: Did you download it from `npm`?

Comment: yes, using the command npm i ng2-prism --save

Comment: Post the error you are getting.

Comment: ERROR in ./~/ng2-src-directive/src/src.directive.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular2/http' in '/home/nitish/uploads/node_modules/ng2-src-directive/src'
 @ ./~/ng2-src-directive/src/src.directive.js 15:13-37
 @ ./~/ng2-src-directive/src.js
 @ ./~/ng2-prism/codeblock.js
 @ ./src/app/add-concept/concept-text/concept-text.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main

Comment: Looks like you need to import module '@angular2/http' in your app module declaration.

Comment: @NitishKumar Seems this is ooooold. Directives are not used anymore. I don't think you'll get this to work at all, since it's not compatible with final release, so if you are using that or newer Angular version, this will not work.

Comment: Thanks @pixelbits